# Zed A.Shaw ex48

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests

I am currently going through Zed A. Shaw's book Learn Ruby the hard way and I am having trouble understanding exercise 48. What I don't understand is this piece of test code:

```
class LexiconTests < Test::Unit::TestCase

Pair = Lexicon::Pair
@@lexicon = Lexicon.new()

def test_directions()
assert_equal([Pair.new(:direction, 'north')], @@lexicon.scan("north"))
result = @@lexicon.scan("north south east")
assert_equal(result, [Pair.new(:direction, 'north'),
             Pair.new(:direction, 'south'),
             Pair.new(:direction, 'east')])
end
```

**Why do we need to use Pair = Lexicon::Pair? What does this piece of code create?**

Comment: It creates a kind of shortcut. It allows you to use `Pair` instead of `Lexicon::Pair` in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @steenslag pointed out, it is assignment, like a shortcut. In some languages, this idea is called an alias.

```rb
Pair = Lexicon::Pair
```

This allows you to refer to `Lexicon::Pair` as `Pair` throughout the rest of the class. The resulting code is less verbose.

Comment: "In some languages, this syntax is called an alias" – In Ruby, this is called *assignment*. It is, in fact, *exactly the same* as the line below.